# How to Delete All Elements That Have an Even Index in Java ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to write a method that removes all ArrayList elements that have an even index. I would like to accomplish this without using any auxiliary data structures. I'm thinking that I should set all even index items to null. Then, I'll try to remove all null elements.

**Example:**

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

Should change to this

```
{1, 3, 5}
```

I was able to find the even positions, but I still can't figure out how to remove them from the ArrayList.

```
public void removeEvenElems() {

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            //how to delete array[i] ?

        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Javadoc for the `ArrayList` class to see if there's a method with a name like `delete` or `remove`?

Comment: That's not possible. You can't remove anything from a List without calling any method. Hint: you'd better start from the end of the list, otherwise, after removal at index 3 the element that was at index 4 is now at index 3.

Comment: Why nit just insert the required elements in new list/arraylist and set the original one null?

Comment: @ Rahul : without calling any method and without using any auxiliary data structure

Comment: @Rahul Yes, except if some object has a reference to the original list.

Comment: Removing element 0, 1, 2...should have the same effect.

Comment: `without calling any method and without use any auxiliary data structure` Let me guess, this is a restriction from a teacher? So pointless ...

Comment: Zizoo and @Tom, you cannot remove an element from an ArrayList without calling a method. You may be able to do that in an array by copying elements from one position to another.

Comment: @Tarik Why do you address me in your comment?

Comment: Your assignment is certainly not "do this without calling any methods".  It might be "do this without *defining* any methods" or something similar, but the only way to interact with an `ArrayList` is by calling its methods, so as posted your question is incoherent.

Comment: @Tom My mistake. For a split second, Zizoo looked like Tom. They call that...temporary insanity :-)

Comment: @Tarik What a relieve :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work try it :

The current is 1 and will increase by 2 every time get in the loop to store the odd elements

```
public void removeEvenElems() {
    current = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        nodes[i] = nodes[current];
        size--;
        current = current + 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use ArrayList or call any additional functions, this code creates a new array

```
public void removeEvenElems(int[] array) {
    int[] temp = new int[array.length];
    int spot = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            temp[spot] = array[i]; 
            spot++;
        }
    }
    System.arraycopy( temp, 0, array, 0, spot+1 );
}
```

Comment: And what is the point of calling this method? It won't change anything. Or let me ask you something: What do you think is the result of `array = temp.clone();` and how does this affect the array that was passed to this method?

Comment: I can't create new array and your solution using .colne(); can't use it

Comment: @RyanShtirmer Please answer this part of my question: *and how does this affect the array that was passed to this method?* Thank you.

Comment: I guess I didn't do my due diligence in understanding .clone and from the (wrong) sample code I looked at I thought it would copy temp into array. I'll fix that in a min.

Comment: `spot+1` doesn't look right and a short example with an array with ten integer elements brought me this: `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 0, 7, 8, 9, 10]`. Try `System.arraycopy(temp, 0, array, 0, array.length);` instead.